# How can I do this query with Laravel Eluquent Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

if I have

```
SELECT * FROM slab WHERE 500 >= min_rate and 500 <= max_rate
```

How can I run this query in Laravel Eloquent way.

Comment: please share if you tired anything in laravel ? its simple query documented in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent:

```
Slab::where('min_rate', '<=', 500)->where('max_rate', '>=', 500)->get();
```

Query Builder:

```
DB::table('slab')->where('min_rate', '<=', 500)->where('max_rate', '>=', 500)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered!

But can you also consider this:

```
Slab::where([ ['min_rate','>=',500], ['max_rate','<=',500] ])->get()
```

No need to chain multiple wheres, you can just use an array of conditions and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the eloquent-query-builder as below:

```
Slab::whereBetween('min_rate',['mix_range_value','max_range_value])->get();
```